# MySQL - Stored Proc creation in code giving syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm baffled by the syntax error I keep getting in MYSQL (ver 5.2) when executing CREATE PROC in code.

The MySQL Proc code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_BillOfMaterialsDetail
(IN InOrderDate DATE,     
IN InProductCode varchar(40),     
IN InRawMaterialProductCode varchar(40) 
) 
BEGIN     
IF EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM basf_rawmaterialplanning.BillOfMaterialsDetail          
WHERE OrderDate = InOrderDate  
and ProductCode = InProductCode          
and RawMaterialProductCode = InRawMaterialProductCode)  
THEN  
DELETE FROM basf_rawmaterialplanning.BillOfMaterialsDetail
WHERE OrderDate = InOrderDate    
AND ProductCode = InProductCode
AND RawMaterialProductCode = InRawMaterialProductCode;
END IF; 
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I build it using a string datatype then execute it against the DB which gives a syntax error.

I'm not to sure what I'm doing wrong?

- Thanks Guys i figured it out, will post the answer as so as StackOverflow allows me to

Comment: What is error message? I've tested it on mysql 5.1.58, works fine for me.

Comment: The error message is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_BillOfMaterialsDetail (IN InOrderDate DATE,' at line 1

The error number is 1064

Comment: @user1495778: The error msg starts right at the beginning of your query. That means there is something wrong how you execute the query. If this create script in another script? How are you executing it?

Comment: @juergend: Yes I can see, but I cannot see where it is wrong. If i run the query in workbench it works fine.

I am declaring a Connection and a Command, setting the command type to commandText, setting the text and executing it.

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCommandText, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Then this a actually no MySQL problem but rather a problem how you execute it in your code. You should post the relevant code.

Comment: @juergend: Thanks, here is the code:

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Connstring);
conn.Open();

String SQLCommandText = "DELIMITER // ";
SQLCommandText = SQLCommandText + "CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_BillOfMaterialsDetail ";
InRawMaterialProductCode; ";
SQLCommandText = SQLCommandText + "END IF;  ";
SQLCommandText = SQLCommandText + "END // ";
SQLCommandText = SQLCommandText + "DELIMITER ; ";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCommandText, conn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

NOTE: Sorry i had to trim some of the procedure out for space

Comment: Do not you want to execute just DELETE statement, without checking existence?

Comment: @Devart: I want to get ride of the syntax error that keeps coming up.

Comment: The problem may be because of you run some statements using one ExecuteNonQuery method. Try to run this code without DELIMITER commands, DELIMITER is not MySQL statement, it is client's command.

Comment: @Devart: I have tired without the DELIMITER command but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys, finally figured it out

I added my script in the MySqlScript object and executed using that class, works 100% without any syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the command for changing delimiter separately and then execute the stored procedure create command.

The system is currently considering it to be one single command and hence the error :)

Comment: string SQLCommandTextPre = "DELIMITER // ";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLCommandTextPre, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

I've pulled it out but when I execute it separately I get a similar error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //' at line 1

Also error number 1064.

Comment: I guess the delimiter cannot be changed through a program. What language are you using for processing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_BillOfMaterialsDetail3(
  IN InOrderDate DATE,
  IN InProductCode varchar(40),
  IN InRawMaterialProductCode varchar(40)) 
DELETE FROM basf_rawmaterialplanning.BillOfMaterialsDetail
WHERE OrderDate = InOrderDate    
AND ProductCode = InProductCode
AND RawMaterialProductCode = InRawMaterialProductCode;
```